# Create xml with artifact files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a hard time getting any information on how to do this.

I want to include a task in my build pipeline that creates an XML file that lists each file of the resulting artifact along with some metadata like checksum, size, etc.

Something like this:

```
<files>
  <file>
    <name>file1.dll</name>
    <path></path>
    <size></size>
    <checksum></checksum>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>file2.dll</name>
    <path></path>
    <size></size>
    <checksum></checksum>
  </file>
</files>
```

I'm thinking I probably need to use a powershell script but how would I go about getting the list of files? I would have to iterate through the list and populate the xml file with that list.

Or is there some task I use to achieve this?

Comment: This seems so use-case specific that its 99.9% likely that you should roll your own, and yes powershell seems appropriate for this.

Comment: Hi @Tralli, How are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Place the resulting artifact files into a specific directory on the agent, such as [$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

In this directory, you can try the steps below:

1. List all files in the directory and subdirectories using the PowerShell command [**Get-ChildItem**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1).

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory -Path path/to/dir -Recurse -Name
   ```
2. In a loop, do the following operations for each files:

- Gets the properties of the file using the PowerShell command [**Get-ItemProperty**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.1).

  ```
  Get-ItemProperty -Path path/to/file | Format-List
  ```

  Or using [**Get-ItemPropertyValue**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue?view=powershell-7.1) to get the properties you specify.

  ```
  Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path path/to/file -Name Property1,Property2,Property3,...
  ```
- Write the properties of the file to the XML file. About working with XML files in PowerShell, below are few related articles as reference.

  - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-to-add-data-to-an-xml-file-using-windows-powershell/
  - https://virtualengine.co.uk/updating-and-writing-xml-files-with-powershell/